# Запуск консольной программы в фоновом режиме C++

Tags: c++, windows

Посредством каких средств языка C++  возможно организовать запуск **консольной** программы на C++ в фоновом режиме? Система Windows.

Comment: Что значит "в фоновом режиме"?

Answer (score 3):

Функция `system` для выполнения команд системой.

По необходимости `cmd /c start ...` или `cmd /k start ...` (для проверки и отладки `/k` скорее всего пригодится) - не проверял. Возможно, к `start` понадобится добавить ключ `/b`.

Answer (score 2):

"Спрятять" консоль в фоновом режиме, видно только в диспетчере задач:

```
#include <Windows.h>
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

Если надо запустить в фоновом режиме, можно использовать функцию [`ShellExecute`](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32ShellExecute.htm):

```
#include <Windows.h>
ShellExecute(nullptr, "open", path, arguments, nullptr, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: не заметил, что 3 года прошло, может кому-то поможет

Comment: Эм.. Это вроде не запуск...

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил